# SSIS Parameter to Variable Switch

Tags: variables, ssis, parameter-passing

I am trying to bind an execution parameter in SSIS to a variable by using a swicth case SQL statement in an SQL Task :

```
SELECT  @[User::StartTime]=
```

`CASE @[$Project::CmdParam]
WHEN 'Full' THEN '20000101000100'
WHEN 'Day-1' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -1, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
WHEN 'Day-2' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -2, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
WHEN 'Day-3' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -3, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
ELSE @[$Project::CmdParam]+'235000'
END`;

I am able to run the query in SSMS but it fails in my package.
It cannot parse the query.

Comment: If you are using a SQL Task, the placeholders for parameters are decided by the driver. Are you using OLE DB or ADO.Net?

Comment: Please ignore my (now deleted) comment. The only way tto troubleshoot this remove most of your code and get a very basic example working and work your way up. And also, please confirm whether your connection is OLEDB or ADO.Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN @[$Project::CmdParam]='Full'  THEN '20000101000100'
     WHEN @[$Project::CmdParam]='Day-1' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -1, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
     WHEN @[$Project::CmdParam]='Day-2' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -2, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
     WHEN @[$Project::CmdParam]='Day-3' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -3, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
     ELSE @[$Project::CmdParam]+'235000'
 END
```

Make sure the  `parameter name` in `Parameter Mapping` page match exactly the same as `@[$Project::CmdParam]` and `CASE WHEN` is used as like above. More important, choose `Single Row` as the `reulst`, and choose `@[User::StartTime]` as the stored variable in `Result` page

**UPDATE**

Like Nick said, switch to `ADO.Net` as the `Connection Type` since you are working with SQL Server, then you could use the above mapping methods, otherwise, you have to use `?`, replace each `@[$Project::CmdParam]` in the query, then the `Parameter Name` for mapping parameters will be, in your case, 0,1,2,3,4, stay same with the result mapping.

**2nd UPDATE**
If you are using `ADO.net` now, forget about 0-4 thing, Paste the following query to you statement in `Execute SQL Task`:

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN @a = 'Full'  THEN '20000101000100'
     WHEN @a = 'Day-1' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -1, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
     WHEN @a = 'Day-2' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -2, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
     WHEN @a = 'Day-3' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(12),DATEADD("Day", -3, GETDATE() ), 112),0,12)+''+'235000')
     ELSE @a + '235000'
 END
```

After pasting, choose `Single Row` as the `Result set` in the same page, next go to the `Parameter Mapping` page, choose `$Project::CmdParam` as the `Variable Name`, type `@a` for the `Parameter Name`, which will map your package variable to @a in the query. Then go to `Result Set` page, `Add` new result, `Result Name` should be `0`, and choose `User::StartTime` as the variable that store the query result.

After all the above steps, should be fine this time.

Comment: You cannot directly parse the value into SSIS variables without mapping parameters and the stored result variable

Comment: Correct. In a SQL task this would require a bunch of `?` symbols, and then they need to be mapped. It does make sense in an _Expression Task_ though.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, before I used `?` to refer all the parameters, but it is kind of hard to find `Parameter Name` for each parameter within a long query, now I prefer using just parameters name directly such as `@parameterName`, then in the  `Parameter Name`, I just need to type the known name for that particular parameter :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I still have a error : [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query. The Query cannot be parsed (Incorrect syntax near the keyword ELSE).

Comment: For the OP's case, I don't need to put `?` after each `WHEN` and then need to count the index number in `Parameter Mapping` page, on the contrast, I just need to put, for example, `@a` after each `WHEN`, then I just need to assign `@a` one time in the `parameter mapping` page

Comment: I believe you need to change the driver from OLE-DB for ADO.Net for that to work (can't find the supporting page right now) but it certainly makes a lot of sense

Comment: Yes, even a better performance cause I always working with SQL Server xD

Comment: SQL Query throws an error message now : [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "SELECT  
CASE WHEN @[$Project::CmdParam]='Full'  T..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near '::'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@".
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
Configured with ADO.net

Comment: Check my update answer, switch to `ADO.net` instead of using `OLE DB`, it even grants you the performance if you are using SQL server

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, I don't understand your update ... I have switched the ConnectionType to ADO.net, the parameterName is set at CParam, how am I supposed to reference it in the Query ? Where should I put the 0->5 values ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been able to progess but  now I have : [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "StartTime": "Result binding by name "StartTime" is not supported for this connection type. ".

Comment: `Result Name` should be `0`, the result is coming from the Query, and you did not specify the result alias, that is why you need to put 0 as the result name, otherwise, you need to `select (...) as StartTime`, then you could use that as the result name

Comment: Got it, just changed it. Nice guys Big up !

Comment: @OwenS Glad you made it !

Comment: Now you could slowly figure out the relationships between the query, parameter mapping and result mapping xD